# Problem Bake Normal Maps from hight poly mesh to low poly mesh

Tags: uv, normal-map

I'm a student and this is my first experience with blender so I'm not an expert.
I'm facing a problem when I try to bake normals in tangent space.

[hippo.blend DOWNLOAD](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/d/6233/hippo.blend)

I have two meshes representing an Hippo, created following some tutorials on youtube. One is high poly, second is low poly.
[image]
[image]

I'm using blender render, as in the tutorials.
I'm able to create an uv map unwrapping the low poly mesh and to do the first bake (select low poly mesh and click bake in render menu).
[image]

It is one day that I'm trying the final step of the tutorial in which I open my uv map in the uv editor, select in bake options "selection to active", I select the high poly mesh, shif+select low poly mesh and I click bake again. I can see that blender do the bake but the result does not change in any way.
[image]

I found the tutorials on youtube typing "Hippo Blender". They are five and I followed everything. But between the video 4 and video 5, I put bones and two animation on my model (not done in the original tutorial). Then I started again with the last tutorial.

I'm using blender 2.79b in the tutorial it is used blender 2.6 I think.
I try to read all the related topics in this forum but I'm not able to find a solution.

If someone can help me I can share the blender project

Thank you in advance

I edit the question after the answers adding some images of the current settings and the normals that I can see.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
as you can see my uv map never changes.

Comment: Which mesh are you selecting first?

Comment: because and for what purpose you have activated the FREESTYLE box ???

Comment: the 2.6 blender tutorial also applies for 2.79b, you can also do normal in cycles 2.79b

Comment: How about increasing the Distance?

Comment: I'm selecting first the hight poly mesh. No reason for freestyle box, today I became crazy and I started to try random options (not a good way to do thing), now I deselected it. I tried to follow a tutorial in cycles but when I press bake blender crash. I played with all the possible parameters but nothing change.

Comment: because your models look transparent? I use blender 2.79b and I see that you use 2.79, so there should not be incompatibilities but I start to think that your blender is damaged or your file is damaged

Comment: your blender or your file has something wrong, because I could never do the Normal Map with your file, however I made a new cube and followed the same step and achieved a map of normal quite good

Comment: yes, probably I messed up the project when I did the bones instead of following directly the last tutorial on the uv map. I think that the only way is restart the hippo project from zero maybe after a new clean installation. Thank you again for the help

Comment: your blender is damaged, your mix file destroyed my blender but reinstalled it and it works again, do the following

Comment: run your blender installer, and tell him to repair and after finishing, you close everything and restart your PC, that should leave repaired and no trace of whatever has damaged your blender and you can continue working
but I suggest that you already use that file opening it more in your blender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in 3D View: you may have made a mistake in the scale, always keep in mind to apply scale <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> select SCALE and ROTATION
2. play a little configuring the maximum distance and the minimum distance, until you get an optimal result or that you like
3. in **edit mode**, remember to apply the **normal orientation** of the faces towards the exterior, to check this you can turn on the normal indicator in  <kbd>mesh display</kbd> , select all and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
4. with respect to the Subdivision surface modifier, you can also play with the levels to see a result that you like, my example is done with this configuration

[Blender Tutorial : Part 17 - Normal Mapping (Blender)](https://youtu.be/bck1eU4e8xo)
[image: example One]
[image: Example Two]
[image: your settings]
[image: adjust face normals]
[image: Subdivision surface modifier]
[image: your subsurf settings]

Comment: yes you have completely reason I made some mistakes in 3d. Now I applied scale and rotation and I can see in the menu that the two object have the same scale and rotation.  In edit mode I applied to both meshes in edit mode normal orientations and if I select to show face normals I can see light blue lines coming out. But when I try the final step nothing change. I really played with the parameters distance and offset.

Comment: in any case really thank you for the answer, at least i learned something

Comment: it's strange, maybe this is a blender file, because it works on all the attempts I had in other blends, can you upload your blend, to be able to check where the error is? [Upload Blender StacK Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: i add a video tutorial, my answer is very good, pleas vote up or accept the answer

Comment: @Muro Conte you have an error in the UV MAP, it is not necessary to have the HiPoly Object UV map, but the LowPoly object must have a map of normal because it is where the information will be deposited, at least that's the way I learned what is done and it has always worked well for me

Comment: you can not create the map of standards in your file something is damaged in your model, because it does not work properly, it appears transparent and even if the UVMaps are fine, I leave that album to you to see how the same process followed but never did. send an error that there is no object to send the information https://imgur.com/sWG8ksg
https://imgur.com/eBTctM9
https://imgur.com/CuH3Nig
https://imgur.com/lBbCeg7
https://imgur.com/VWkjjtJ
https://imgur.com/a0AgcMe
https://imgur.com/Qh2a9VA